# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) - Ruby

Tags: ruby

I had a test suite( hellow_world_test.rb) which has the following

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
begin
  gem 'minitest', '>= 5.0.0'
  require 'minitest/autorun'
  require_relative 'hello_world'
rescue Gem::LoadError => e
  puts "\nMissing Dependency:\n#{e.backtrace.first} #{e.message}"
  puts 'Minitest 5.0 gem must be installed for the xRuby track.'
rescue LoadError => e
  puts "\nError:\n#{e.backtrace.first} #{e.message}"
  puts DATA.read
  exit 1
end

# Test data version:
# deb225e Implement canonical dataset for scrabble-score problem (#255)

class HelloWorldTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_no_name
    assert_equal 'Hello, World!', HelloWorld.hello()
  end

  def test_sample_name 
    assert_equal 'Hello, Alice!', HelloWorld.hello('Alice')
  end

  def test_other_sample_name
    assert_equal 'Hello, Bob!', HelloWorld.hello('Bob')
  end
end

__END__
```

On the basis of that I had implemented the code like  below

```
class HelloWorld
    def self.hello
        "Hello, World!"
    end

    def self.hello(named)
        "Hello, #{named}!"
    end
end
```

And right now my two test cases are passing and the first test case is returning

> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
>       /Users/vijay/Codes/Ruby/ruby/hello-world/hello_world.rb:7:in `hello'
>       hello_world_test.rb:21:in`test_no_name'

Can some body help me on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no method overloading by params in Ruby. With your second definition of `hello` you overwrote the first one. Anyway, you can obtain the same behaviour with just one method with a default value for the parameter.

```
def self.hello(named = 'World')
  "Hello, #{named}!"
end
```